# Do flurry's video interstitials get served automatically now?

Tags: flurry

I've just finished integrating flurry's api (FlurryAds) into my app and have received static test ads and live ads successfully - but no video ads.

I know the old app circle code required you to set a flag to allow video ads but I can find no such thing with the new api and looking through the docs I can find no information on how to test if they are working.

Am I missing something or do I just need to keep trying until a video ad is served too me?

```
void AnalyticX::flurryShowAd() {
AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
UIViewController* appView = (UIViewController*)app.viewController;

if([FlurryAds adReadyForSpace:@"INTERSTITIAL_MAIN_VIEW"]) {
    [FlurryAds displayAdForSpace:@"INTERSTITIAL_MAIN_VIEW" onView:appView.view];
}
else {
    [FlurryAds fetchAdForSpace:@"INTERSTITIAL_MAIN_VIEW" frame:appView.view.frame size:FULLSCREEN];
    [FlurryAds ]
}
}

void AnalyticX::flurryFetchAd() {
AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
UIViewController* appView = (UIViewController*)app.viewController;

if([FlurryAds adReadyForSpace:@"INTERSTITIAL_MAIN_VIEW"]) {
    // Don't fetch an ad if we have one ready
}
else {
    [FlurryAds fetchAdForSpace:@"INTERSTITIAL_MAIN_VIEW" frame:appView.view.frame size:FULLSCREEN];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is random depending on the adverts served to you. After experimenting for a few days I finally received a video interstitial without changing any code.

Comment: Please explain me how u got the video ads ... i face same problem  since last few days .....

Comment: As mentioned above its random depending on the adverts which the server has available. There is no "setting" which turns videos on or off.

I would only imagine that video interstitial are rarer because they carry a higher price tag.